# What parameters to use to improve performance of writing dataframes to a Parquet file?

Tags: python, performance, apache-spark, pyspark, parquet

I'm working with some data and my code is taking more than one minute to write a dataframe in a Parquet file. The dataframe has around 90000 lines and 10 columns. It's my first time using spark, so I'm not sure about the time performance here, but I think this is too much time. I've read some texts to get a better performance writing to Parquet, but it didn't help yet. I would like to know what type of parameters I could use to get a better performance, or if maybe my data is too small, and that's the normal time.

I have a for loop that iterates in my dataframe date column. It iterates on each day and writes in the file. Currently on the test, I have only one day in the column, so it iterates in this for loop only once, and it takes about 10 seconds to perform all the other operations (I didn't include the code for the other operations in the dataframe), but when it gets to this line to write the file, it takes more than 1 minute.

```
if i == 0:
    df.write.mode('overwrite').parquet(self.files['parquet'])
else:
    df.write.mode('append').parquet(self.files['parquet'])
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a for loop for saving a Spark dataframe. Just do:

```
df.write.mode('overwrite').parquet(path)
```

Comment: The for loop is to make the other operations, not only to write the file.

Comment: spark uses lazy evaluation which means nothing happens until an ```action``` is executed which in your case is ```write``` ... the above will process all of your operations

Comment: Do you mean that the operations are being executed when the write happens? Example: I have some withColumn() method operations in the dataframe before the write, so those operations are happening when the write was called?

Comment: Yes the withColumn operations will execute when you call write.
Also, in Spark in most cases you should never use for-loops, that is not what Spark was made for. 
What are you calculating in your for-loops?

Comment: Yea I have to improve my code a lot, I'm reading about it, I have to make some changes to take the for loops out. I'm doing some operations after iterate over each day in a data frame column. Thanks for the answer.